CustomerError: The size of the build output (260454077) exceeds the max allowed size of 230686720 bytes
I am try to build my nextjs app in aws amplify
My nodejs v20 and nextjs v14
ERROR:
!!! CustomerError: The size of the build output (260454077) exceeds the max allowed size of230686720 bytes. Please reduce the size ofyour build output and try again.
After that Deploy cancelled
This is my amplify.yml file.
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - nvm install 20
            - nvm use 20
            - npm install
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: .next
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
          - .next/cache/**/*


it should deploy properly.

If add negative vot then  you should add some comment what's wrong.

There was some library issue like my project was canvas library after replace this library my build output reduce by 100 times. It's so funny and reality.
